# Hodge-$\star$ operator computation on a smooth two-dimensional manifold

Tags: differential-geometry, riemannian-geometry, laplacian, hodge-theory

Let $(x,y)$ be the local coordinates on a Riemannian manifold $M$ with $\dim(M) =2$. Let $\star$ denote the Hodge-$\star$ operator, and let $g = g_{ij}$ denote the Riemannian metric on $M$.

I am attempting to compute the formula for the Laplace--Beltrami acting on 1-forms of $M$. I have been stuck on computing that action of the Hodge-$\star$ operator on $dx$ and $dy$, and this is what I would like help with.

We know: $\star(1) = \sqrt{\det(g)} dx \wedge dy$ and $\star(dx \wedge dy) = \dfrac{1}{\sqrt{\det(g)}}$. If the metric is simply $\delta_{ij}$, then we know that $\star dx$ and $\star dy = -dx$, but I am interested in the case when the metric $g_{ij} \neq \delta_{ij}$.

I would appreciate any help with this, and if you need any further details, please let me know.

I have been aware of the following, but has been of little or no avail:\begin{eqnarray*}
dx \wedge \star dx &=& \sqrt{\det(g_{ij})} g^{11} dx \wedge dy,\\
dy \wedge \star dx &=& \sqrt{\det(g_{ij})} g^{12} dy \wedge dx
\end{eqnarray*}

From this, it is claimed that we deduce: $$\star dx = \sqrt{\det(g_{ij})}(g^{11} dy - g^{12}dx).$$

This is not clear.

Comment: Why not? You know you have some expression $*dx = adx + bdy$ and you know what happens when you wedge with $dx$ and $dy$. Though your second to last displayed line should say $dy \wedge dx$.

Comment: @MikeMiller I apologise, but I do find this comment illuminating. Can you please elaborate? Thanks in advance.

Comment: I am not sure how: can you be precise about what should be elaborated? (I am glad to write an answer but am not sure what to add.)

Comment: @MikeMiller Actually no, I understand what you have said in your first comment now. I also realise how simple this is, thank you! It just was not clicking for me. Thanks Mike! If you post an answer, I am happy to accept it and upvote it. I appreciate your help :)

Comment: No problem at all. In fact, I suggest you write up the answer yourself - I will gladly upvote it!

Comment: @MikeMiller Hi Mike, I was reading over the wikipedia page: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hodge_star_operator and, in particular, was looking at the formula for the Hodge-$\star$ operator given in the _Expression in Index Notation_ section. The first displayed formula in this section seems to assert that $$\star dx = \sqrt{\det(g_{ij})} g^{12} \varepsilon_{12} dy = \sqrt{\det(g_{ij})} g^{12} dy.$$ This contradicts my computation, can you inform me on what is going on here?

Comment: (I will admit that I never checked the two formulas you claimed, just that it then followed what the answer should be.) Expect an answer late tonight.

Comment: @MikeMiller Thanks for your time :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Write $\star dx = P dx + Q dy$ for some $P,Q$ to be determined. We have $$dx \wedge \star dx = P dx \wedge dx + Q dx \wedge dy = Q dx \wedge dy,$$ and $$dy \wedge \star dx = P dy \wedge dx + Q dy \wedge dy = P dy \wedge dx.$$

With $dx \wedge \star dx = \sqrt{\det(g_{ij})} g^{11} dx \wedge dy$, we observe that $Q = \sqrt{\det(g_{ij})} g^{11}$. Similarly, with $dy \wedge \star dx = \sqrt{\det(g_{ij})} g^{12} dx \wedge dy$, we have $P = - g^{12} \sqrt{\det(g_{ij})}$. Hence, $$\star dx = \sqrt{\det(g_{ij})} g^{11} dy - \sqrt{\det(g_{ij})} g^{12} dx,$$ as claimed.